# Ractive computed attributes returned in get()

Tags: ractivejs

ref [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nightingill/1z5prku6/)

html:

```
<main />
<div id='result' />
```

code:

```
window.ractive = new Ractive({
  el: 'main',
  template: '<p>a thing called {{thing}}</p>',
  computed: { thing : function(){return "kablooie"} }
});
$('#result').html(JSON.stringify(ractive.get()))
```

The ractive.get() here *does* return the value of the attribute "thing". Even though the docs say that computed attributes are not returned by get().

Is this intentional behaviour or a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In edge Ractive (will be 0.8) which you are using, we added the computed and mapped properties to the root get via `ractive.get()` as a feature request.

See [this issue](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/2518#issuecomment-212735707) for current proposal to be able to get only the root data object via `ractive.get('.')`, which would mean:

```
window.ractive = new Ractive({
  el: 'main',
  data: { foo: 'foo' },
  template: '<p>a thing called {{thing}}</p>',
  computed: { thing : function(){return "kablooie"} }
});

console.log( JSON.stringify( ractive.get() ) );
// { foo: 'foo', thing: 'kablooie' }

console.log( JSON.stringify( ractive.get('.') ) );
// { foo: 'foo' }
```

Comment: thank you, Marty, and thanks for all your contributions to ractive. Just to mention, then that the 'edge' docs don't yet reflect this change.